# comma separated values in mysql in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Retrieving data from MySQL in Code Igniter..

Currently my query is this:

```
SELECT `gs_team_members`.`team_id`, 
    `gs_users`.* 
FROM (`gs_team_members`)
JOIN `gs_users` 
ON `gs_users`.`id` = `gs_team_members`.`member_id` 
JOIN `gs_user_privileges` 
ON `gs_user_privileges`.`user_id` = `gs_users`.`id` 
WHERE `gs_users`.`user_type` = 'member' 
AND `gs_users`.`id` != '4' 
AND `gs_user_privileges`.`privilege_id` = 7 
AND FIND_IN_SET('19', submenu_previlege) 
AND `gs_team_members`.`team_id` IN ('1', '2') 
AND `team_id` = '2' 
GROUP BY `gs_users`.`name` 
ORDER BY `gs_users`.`name` ASC;
```

Working fine when `gs_team_members.team_id`=1 (means only one numeric id). I want it to work for `gs_team_members.team_id`=1,2 (means multiple comma separated ids)

Comment: if you want to use comma separated values as searching so you may use like query instead of FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Write IN ( 1 , 2 )

Comment: `like` wont work @krunalnerikar because if you search for `1` it retrive all data which have a 1. For exampe 11,12,13... and so on. Best practice is `IN` function alone

Comment: 1 IN (1,2,3).. is perfect i know
but how to use when
"1,2,3" IN (1,2,3)

Comment: Then According to me do this as condition base from php side

Answer (score 0):

this is one example.. please try this one

SELECT * FROM `user` where FIND_IN_SET(user_id, ('1,36,37'))